# Django: How to get SUM of all rows related to a single row

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have 2 models. serviceinvoice and invoiceitems. invoiceitems model is linked to serviceinvoice with a foreign key.

Now for a single invoice how do I get the total discount amount.?
Annotate does not work since it's for a single row only.
**Models.py**

```
class serviceinvoice(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,related_name='invoice')    
    invoice_number=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    invoice_date = models.DateField()


class serviceinvoiceitems(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,related_name='serviceinvoiceitem')
    company=models.ForeignKey(Organisation,related_name='sitemcomp')
    invoice_number=models.ForeignKey(serviceinvoice,related_name='serviceitems1')
    discount = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    discount_amount = models.FloatField(null=True,blank=True,default=0)
    Amount=models.FloatField()
    discription=models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
```

I am trying in view:

```
invoice_detailmain = serviceinvoice.objects.get(pk=pk)
dis_value_total = Sum('invoice_detailmain__serviceitems1__discount_amount')
```

It's not giving the sum of discount_amount.
What is the solution and how to show it in the template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the reverse relationship:

```
invoice_detailmain = serviceinvoice.objects.get(pk=pk)
dis_value_total = sum(i.discount_amount for i in invoice_detailmain.serviceinvoiceitems_set.all())
```

Note this is using the built-in `sum` and not `Sum` from the django ORM.

The other way to do it, is to annotate the entire queryset, then fetch your individual invoice:

```
i = serviceinvoice.objects.annotate(Sum('serviceinvoiceitems__discount_amount')).get(pk=pk)
```

This works because `annotate` will return another queryset, so you can chain the operations together.